# NSURL to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I using this function to get a URL from a String, but how can I get it back?

```
- (NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding forString:(NSString *)string {
    string = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ", CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
    return string;
}
```

Comment: That my friend is one of the ugliest lines of code I have ever seen.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Lucky you :):):)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
```

BTW. If use `NSURL` for file url, be sure to use `[url path]` to get the unescaped path string, not by `[url absoluteString]`.

Comment: On ios7: [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; works

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
```

for this purpose.

Comment: Ah, so your title is misleading. You don't want to get an NSString from an NSURL, but unescape an URL-escaped string...

Comment: `urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];`

Comment: @AlexSalom and repeat that for every escape sequence :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:your_url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

may this will help you

Comment: That doesn't remove %20 as a space in the URL

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer myself:

```
- (NSString *)decodedURLString {
    NSString *string = (__bridge NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                          (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                          CFSTR(""),
                                                                                          CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

    return string;
}
```

and for encode:

```
- (NSString *)encodedURLString {
    NSString *string = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                           (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                           NULL,
                                                                           CFSTR(":/=,!$&'()*+;[]@#?"),
                                                                           CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

    return string;
}
```